# Is it possible to convert 12V dc to 220V AC?

Tags: current, ac, dc, converter

One of my friend said it's possible to convert a 12V dc to 220V, 
I cann't belive that it's possible because IF that's possible we don't have to have too many power plants for our power needs.

There is something that I am missing, Please help me with information and Explain me why this is possible if possible or if not why not.

Comment: "because IF that's possible we don't have to have too many power plants for our power needs"  Huh?

Comment: @Lundin,  if 12V can be 230V , then  We can make 230V from small 12V wine turbine which is really easy. I want to know details.

Comment: ONE google search: "12V 230V inverter"

Comment: Why do you think the voltage matters? The reason we have 230VAC in power cables isn't because its such a useful voltage for home electronics - it is in fact the opposite. 230VAC is used because of historical reasons, but also because it's convenient to use higher voltages across longer distances. And yes it is of course possible to transform one voltage to another, see for example https://www.amazon.com/Vehicle-Inverter-Converter-Portable-Transformer/dp/B00SLH9L5Y

Comment: So is it possible to use a 1.5V battery and convert to 230V and then use it to power a Home

Comment: No, because it doesn't contain enough capacity... I think you might want to start studying the differences between voltage and current.

Comment: Yes it is possible to use a 1.5V battery to power a house, but it would have to be a much larger 1.5V battery than anything you have ever seen in your life before. And it would be a lot easier if the battery voltage were higher.

Comment: The bit that costs the money is **power**, which is volts * current. When you increase the voltage, the current drops and *vice versa*.

Comment: Power is volts times amps (P=I\*V) but *cable power loss* (i.e. the power lost in the cables) is amps squared times the cable resistance (P=I^2\*R). This means if you use twice the voltage, you need half the current to provide the same amount of power (V\*I = 2V\*0.5I) but now your cable loss is only 1/4 of what it was before assuming you use the same cable (I **^2** \*R). This is why the main lines from a power station use 200-400 KILOvolts, they need to move GIGAwatts and even at nearly half a million volts, that's still a couple *thousand* amps and still needs a cable as thick as your arm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are missing is any notion of power and conservation of energy. In order to supply a house with 220V at, say, 50A, you need 11000 Watts. Converting from battery to AC is not perfectly efficient, so you would probably need to take more like 13000W from your battery. So that is over 1000 Amps at 12V. I think you will find that an automotive battery simply cannot deliver 13000 Watts at all, even for a short time.

Let's ignore the current limitation, and just look at power. The naive calculation is 12V * 50Ah = 600 Wh. Meaning you could theoretically supply 13000W for a few seconds. But 600 Wh is only available if the battery is discharged slowly. When it is discharged rapidly, it wastes much of its internal energy heating up the battery.

Which brings us to another problem. Trying to discharge a battery this fast will probably destroy it from heating.

It IS possible to run a house from an inverter, but it requires a large battery bank, and it is generally much better to use higher voltage DC (for example 48V). Because the input current will be lower at higher voltage, and this allows more reasonable wire diameters to be used.

Comment: 220x50 is not 1100

Comment: Oh. Great. So my whole answer is stupid now and has to be re-written. But, thanks, @WillDean.

Comment: Actually, you made a compensatory error when dividing 1300/12 and getting 'over 1000', so it's not as bad as you fear.

Comment: Two wrongs don't make a right. But three lefts do.